# building a predicate with no value expression

Tags: c#, linq, include, predicates

I'm trying to create an `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` for `IQueryable<T>.OrderByDescending()`

This is in my base class for `FindLast` and I found that `LastOrDefault` will not work and thus an `OrderByDescending.FirstOrDefault` was necessary.  However as stated it is  a base class and the sort by method is the primary key so it has to be `tableName + "PK"`

Here is the code so far:

```
Expression<Func<T, object>> predicate2 = null;
string propertyName = string.Empty;
propertyName = typeof(T).Name + "PK";

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
// x.PK
MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] { parameter };
predicate2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, parameters);

result = query.Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(predicate2).FirstOrDefault(); // .LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out... Needed to change predicate2 to appropriate data type

```
Expression <Func <T, Int32>> predicate2
```